# "Down by a point" meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does **'The Foxes are up to bat and down by a point'** mean?

Does this mean the Foxes are behind their opponent by one point?

Comment: Only uneducated old people watch baseball when boxing, tennis, ice hockey, and verismo opera are available.

Comment: Ricky should be banned from attempting humor.

Comment: Point? That's not baseball. You're thinking backgammon.

Comment: If you have not gotten a good answer, try http://sports.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a correct assumption.

Also, "up to bat" is a reference for being your turn to attack on baseball. [Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up_to_bat).

Comment: Is "down by a point" different from "one down"? It confuses me because when we say "one down," I think it means there are things that need to be accomplished...say 3 for example. And means, you've accomplished one and you have 2 more to go.

Comment: @marsce ... yes, those are different.

Comment: To be even more confusing it is context dependent - you could be   “1 down” if one player is in the penalty box.

Comment: The reference is probably to cricket not baseball because baseball uses runs not points

Comment: @Jim Cricket scoring also uses [runs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_%28cricket%29).

Comment: @Lawrence - what is this then? http://www.ecb.co.uk/news/domestic/lv-county-championship/liverpool-victoria-county-championship-scoring-of-points

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure, cricket isn't my first language :) . There are many [forms of cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_of_cricket) but I think they all use runs. On the other hand, baseball is also said to [equate points with runs](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/baseball.htm), so perhaps this is just a matter of terminology. From what I understand about cricket, though (which isn't a lot), they typically need to keep track of two numbers: runs and wickets. So a single number (points) isn't going to be enough to tell the whole story.

Comment: Baseball never calls runs "points," so this is some kind of convoluted metaphor.  The linked article only mentions points because if you don't understand baseball, "points" is a way to explain what "runs" means.  (Actually, they could have used "scores" too.) But within the game of baseball itself, no one says "points."  Ever.

Comment: Being "one down" I think one could assume also as being "one man down" (as in hockey's penalty box or a red card in football), in baseball, probably that you have two more attempts at the bat instead of three. I do agree though that the text could be talking to people who don't know much about baseball. If it's cricket then, good luck, I have no idea how it's even played. :D